# Dynamic Template Controls

Tags: asp.net

On !PostBack dynamic templates are created based on the number of rows needed for check boxes.  The control id's are chkbox_id.  I am unable to retrieve the dynamic check boxes via the following code and NullReferenceException is always thrown.

The code before loops through the gridview rows, then datatable dt references the possible number of dynamic columns.

```
    for (int i = 0; i < dt.Rows.Count; i++)
    {
        string id = dt.Rows[i]["id"].ToString();

        CheckBox cb = (CheckBox)row.FindControl("ckbox_" + id);
        if (cb.Checked)
        { // do things  }

    }
```

Checkboxes defined here within page load:

```
if (!Page.IsPostBack)
{
    foreach (DataRow dRow in dt.Rows)
    {
        TemplateField ckhColumn = new TemplateField();
        ckhColumn.HeaderTemplate = new GridViewTemplate(ListItemType.Header, dRow["name"].ToString());
        ckhColumn.ItemTemplate = new GridViewTemplate(ListItemType.Item, "ckbox_" + dRow["id"].ToString());
        gvProductPriceList.Columns.Add(ckhColumn);
    }           
}
```

Let me know if I need to clarify anything else.

Comment: Can you show the code where you define the checkboxes?

Comment: Correct me if I am wrong but after some further research it appears FindControl will not work within a master page...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not positive on this, and I don't have a minute to try it, but it might work if you do a `row.Parent.FindControl(...)`. Also, if you use the `as` operator instead of a direct cast, you won't have the null reference exception (i.e. you can check for it):

```
CheckBox cb = row.Parent.FindControl("ckbox_" + id) as CheckBox;
if (cb != null)
{
    // ...
}
```

Comment: I appreciate your help.  This did not work as the control could not be found.  I solved the problem by using a check-box list within a template item.